# Group dictionary to other dictionary via intermediate map

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary that map between certain keys

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ {"A", "One"}, {"B", "One"}, {"C", "Two"} };
```

I also have a dictionary containing values

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, double>() { {"A", 2.0}, {"B", 1.0}, {"C", 1.0} };
```

I want to map the values into a third dictionary so that the value of `map` is the key of the new dictionary. I.e. I want the new dictionary to be

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, double>() {{"One", 3.0}, {"Two", 1.0}};
```

This can of course be achieved using loops like so

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, double>();
foreach (var kv in values)
{
    var key = map[kv.Key];
    var value = kv.Value;

    if (result.TryGetValue(key, out var temp))
        result[key] = value + temp;
    else
        result.Add(key, value);
}
```

Or something like that...

But is it possible to do this in a one-liner using linq?

Comment: Why do you need linq in one line? In any case after this  a compiler converts it in a set of for each loops that sometimes can be ugly. It is better to make your own for each loops , especialy if the code is critical.

Comment: Well, I don't "need" linq in one line. I am trying to learn a bit of linq as I code, and this problem is one I haven't been able to figure out. My current code is a function using for loops as you propose.

Comment: Is it working properly?

Comment: I believe it is... I think I see where you are going with that question :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. The best is an enemy of good. Better a diamond with a flaw than a pebble without.

Comment: I will take your advice to heart.

Comment: Thanks. I like much more your code, then the answer  of Volodymyr Baydalka. At least your code is maintainable and predictable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var result = map
 .Join(values, x => x.Key, y => y.Key, (x, y) => (x.Value, y.Value))
 .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Sum(s => s.Item2));
```

DotNet Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tWd9j5

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for Join method

```
var result = map.Join(values, x => x.Key, y => y.Key, (x, y) => (x.Value, y.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, y => y.Item2);
```

And to handle duplication of value

```
var result = map
            .Join(values, x => x.Key, y => y.Key, (x, y) => (x.Value, y.Value))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.First().Item2);
```

Comment: Hi, your code doesn't seem to work...  I get an error "System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: One"'

Comment: It's because map contains value duplication. To handle duplication you just need modify it a little

Comment: I am aware of the value duplication. If you look in the code I posted you will see how I handled it. Your code does not produce the correct answer... It seems you are not summing the overlapping values. But its close :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

```
var result = (from m in map
                      join v in values
                      on m.Key equals v.Key
                      group v.Value by m.Value into sameVal
                      select new { MValue = sameVal.Key, VValue = sameVal.Sum() }).ToDictionary(a => a.MValue, b => b.VValue);
```

Comment: Hi. I know the map repeats one of the values. It is supposed to be that way.

Comment: You can't use duplicate values as keys. It's logically expected to be a unique key for each value.

Comment: I know all this. If you look at the code I posted, you will see that you need to sum those values.

Comment: Now I get your question. Edited the answer

Comment: Yes. Now its working. Thank you Bazil.